# Aonde está localizado o código fonte dos comandos do Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, linux

Aonde fica o código fonte dos comandos do Python3? Quero ver o código fonte de comandos como `len()`, `count()`, `find()`, etc etc.
Eu uso Linux Mint, já olhei e olhei, mas não acho...

Quem puder ajudar agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código fonte do CPython 3 fica [nesse repositório](https://github.com/python/cpython). Você provavelmente não consegue achar porque tem instalado só o Python compilado, que não inclui o código fonte (o CPython, interpretador principal, é escrito em C).

Pros objetos built-in, funções como `len` são definidas no código em C. Por exemplo, dê um Ctrl + F procurando por "list_length" na [fonte de uma lista](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c).

Se você tem uma classe em Python que define a função `__len__`, então essa será a função utilizada pelo Python pra descobrir o tamanho do objeto, mas esse não é o caso pros built-ins escritos em C.